# Javascript is not working like it should

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made a form which shows different number of stars when roll button is pressed but there is no output.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Roll a die</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="dieForm">
        <input type="text" id="die" readonly="true" size="18">
        <input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="Roll()">
    </form>
<script>
    function Roll(){
        var dieNumber, dieDots, dots;
        dieDots="* ";
        dieNumber=math.round(6*math.random());
        for(dots=2;dots<=dieNumber;dots=dots+1){
          dieDots="* ";
        }
        document.getElementById("die").value=dieDots;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean no output? is the output wrong or there is no output at all? did you check console for errors?

Comment: btw your logic inside the forloop is missing a string concat operation. it must be `dieDots +="* "` Also place the script tag in the head section.

Comment: i've corrected string concat but still no output at all.

Comment: Please check the console window for any errors. Press F12 to open developer tools and in that look into the console section.

Comment: this is the error:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: math is not defined
    at Roll (Roll_a_die.html:16)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Roll_a_die.html:10)

Comment: why math functions are not working

Comment: It must be `Math` not `math`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few errors. First it cannot be `math` it needs to be `Math`, then `+=` inside loop. here is working one:

```
<head>
<title>Roll a die</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="dieForm">

        <input type="text" id="die" readonly="true" size="18">
        <input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="Roll()">
    </form>
<script>
    function Roll(){
      var dieNumber, dieDots, dots;
      dieDots="* ";
      dieNumber=Math.round(6*Math.random());
      for(dots=2;dots<=dieNumber;dots++){
          dieDots+="* ";
      }
      document.getElementById("die").value=dieDots;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you written math and it is should be Math